# Using values in one list as indices to access a second list

Tags: python

In Python, say I have a list that contains 2-element sublists like

```
coords = [ [2,1],[3,4],[5,2]]
```

and I want to use these as the indices for a 2-dimensional array, data_array, for example

```
data_array = [
[5,56,34,78, ..........],
[45,23,76,3,98, .......],
[2,34,67,54,87,21, ....],
[ ....],
[ ....],
[ ....],
...... ,
[ ....]
]
```

So `[2,1]` will refer to `data_array[2][1]`, `[3,4]` will refer to `data_array[3][4]`, and so on.

What is the most efficient/simplest way to do this?

I could code something like

```
n  = len(coords)    
for idx0 in range[n]:
    for idx1 in range[n]:
        print(data_array[coords[idx0][idx1]])
```

but that feels a little clumsy. Is there a more “direct” way to use the sub-lists in coords as the indices to data_array? I can change the format of coords if that helps.

Comment: numpy arrays support indexing in a way you might like

Comment: @JonSG - I will explore that library - see what happens then post my results as a comment. If I can get it to work - I will let you post the answer and claim the glory.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly get something simpler with a library like `numpy` or `pandas` that have more options for indexing multi-dimensional arrays, but in vanilla Python the simplest would be a list comprehension:

```
my_values = [data_array[x][y] for x,y in coords]
```

Note this only works if you can guarantee the coords always have two elements, otherwise you'll get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.
The slightly safer, slightly more verbose option is:

```
my_values = [data_array[x[0]][x[1]] for x in coords]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might get a cleaner attempt if you leverage unpacking.

Given:

```py
data = [[10*x+i for i in range(10)] for x in range(10)]
coords = [[2,1], [3,4], [5,2]]
```

You can likely get the results you see via:

```py
for x, y in coords:
    print(data[x][y])
```

You might put those results in a list as well using:

```py
results = [data[x][y] for x,y in coords]
print(results)
```

If you used `numpy` though, you can do this:

```py
import numpy
data = numpy.array(data)
for coord in coords:
    print(data[tuple(coord)])
```

of better yet, if you set `coords` as a list of tuples or cast it to that:

```
import numpy

data = [[10*x+i for i in range(10)] for x in range(10)]
data = numpy.array(data)
coords = [[2,1], [3,4], [5,2]]
coords = map(tuple, coords)

for coord in coords:
    print(data[coord])
```

which seems fairly close to what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can efficiently achieve this using list comprehension. Instead of resorting to nested loops, you can directly construct a new list that associates the coordinates from coords with the corresponding elements in data_array. Here's the code snippet:

```
coords = [[2, 1], [3, 4], [5, 2]]
    data_array = [
        [5, 56, 34, 78, ...],
        [45, 23, 76, 3, 98, ...],
        [2, 34, 67, 54, 87, 21, ...],
        # ... (other rows)
    ]
    
    result = [data_array[i][j] for i, j in coords]
    
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code. For the sake of checking the output,I've reduced the lengths and values of both the lists.

```
coords = [ [1,1],[0,3],[2,2]]
data_array = [
[5,56,34,78],
[45,23,76,3,98],
[2,34,67,54,87,21]
]
for x in coords:
    print(data_array [x[0]] [x[1]])
```

If you want the output as list:

```
l = [data_array [x[0]] [x[1]] for x in coords]
print(l)
```